# Parsing timezone abbreviations in DST

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activesupport

I have a service that returns the current time information for various locations which returns timezones using the 3 letter abbreviation format. E.g. `EST`, `PST`, `EDT`, etc. However, which ActiveSupport seems aware of the `EDT` variant, it does not seem to be able to parse it. Example:

The full name of the timezone is converted to `EST` or `EDT` according to the date

```
Time.new(2017, 12, 1).in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')
=> Fri, 01 Dec 2017 00:00:00 EST -05:00
Time.new(2017, 12, 1).in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)').zone
=> "EST"
Time.new(2017, 10, 1).in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')
=> Sun, 01 Oct 2017 00:00:00 EDT -04:00
Time.new(2017, 10, 1).in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)').zone
=> "EDT"
```

However, the inverse cannot identify the DST variant abbreviation:

```
Time.new(2017, 12, 1).in_time_zone('EST').zone
=> "EST"
Time.new(2017, 12, 1).in_time_zone('EST')
=> Fri, 01 Dec 2017 00:00:00 EST -05:00
Time.new(2017, 10, 1).in_time_zone('EDT')
ArgumentError: Invalid Timezone: EDT
from /home/erich/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/zones.rb:72:in `rescue in find_zone!'
```

The full name is fine (and probably preferable) for my case, as it correctly identifies the status of DST based on the date. So if I can derive the long form, I can simply use that for any day of the year. Is there any method provided by rails (4) that will provide that mapping such as:

```
some_method('EST')
=> "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"
some_method('EDT')
=> "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"
```

If not, is there some other way I can deal with `xDT` forms?

Comment: There's some confusion here - EST and EDT are not zones, they are offsets.  "Eastern Time (US & Canada)" is the zone, I'm not sure how to best get the available 3 charcter offsets for a zone but that's what you're looking for.

Comment: It's not a one-to-one mapping. For example, both `Eastern Time (US & Canada)` and `Indiana (East)` have the abbreviation `EST` / `EDT`.

Comment: @Anthony I could definitely be wrong, but I have never seen a non-numeric value referred to as "offset". The confusion is deep within Activesupport if that's the case. `.zone` returns e.g. `'EST'` (Eastern Standard Time), where `gmt_offset`, `utc_offset`, `formatted_offset` return... well, offsets. ;)

Answer (score 0):

There's a [TimezoneParser gem](https://github.com/davispuh/TimezoneParser) that might be handy?

Comment: I'm always a bit hesistant to use a gem with only one committer and low adoption in production code, but I'll check it out. Thanks for the recommendation.